# C# ThreadPool one thread blocks other?

Tags: c#, threadpool, block

I have a C# console app where I have a threadpool. In the threadpool there will be a class thats executes a continuous method (till it has ran for a certain period of time or when it knows when to stop). The method connects to an HttpWebResponse stream and keep reeding it.

The problem is that for a short time all threads just do their things but then only one threads keep showing it's output and the rest is waiting for that thread.

This is the method that is executed for each thread.

```
function void ReadStream()
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        String domain = streamingUrl

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(domain);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();

        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count;
        do
        {
            // fill the buffer with data
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                try
                {
                    mySqlManager.SaveResult(tempString);

                    Console.WriteLine("Been here");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);
    }
```

Comment: You can hit Break All in the debugger, when the app is in the state where the other threads are waiting on the one thread.  That might show you exactly what these threads are waiting on.  Also check for any exceptions in your empty catch block, that might be hiding something interesting.

Comment: Shouldnt you be creating new instances of the streamReader, using the new keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should wrap both `response` and `resStream` in `using` blocks to ensure they are disposed of properly.

Second, putting *long-running threads* in the `ThreadPool` is not really the best idea, in my opinion. The idea of the `ThreadPool` class is that it allows you to queue up relatively small actions where spawning a new thread for each one would be wasteful. If you have operations that will take a significant amount of time to run, I would advise actually creating dedicated `Thread` objects for each.

Comment: I suspect the Thread.Sleep(1000) in the thread pool causes this problem. I am also facing the same problem. The question is why the thread pool thread blocks other threads?

Answer (score 0):

You should really break in the debugger to find out where each thread is stopped at, but my guess is that the culprit is

> mySqlManager.SaveResult(tempString);

mySqlManager appears to be a class property, which means you need to be especially careful about thread safety. Make sure that SaveResult() is thread-safe; if not, then you need to make your call to SaveResult() thread-safe with locking.

Good luck!